# Загрузка страницы после удачного POST запроса

Tags: macos, objective-c, http, post, javascript

Доброго времени суток.
Я только учу Obj-c. 
При старте программы у меня открывается loginWindowController, там я ввожу логин и пароль. После нажатия на кнопку войти отправляются два запроса, с помощью AFNetworking, для ввода двух паролей. 
Получается так что когда я отправляю первый запрос на game.php то появляется страница с вводом второго пароля по адресу game.php :

```
 <head>
    <link href="./css/nl_try.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
    <SCRIPT src="./js/nl_main.js"></SCRIPT> 
    <SCRIPT src="./js/nl_try.js"></SCRIPT>
    </head>
    <body onResize="resizer()">
        <script type="text/javascript">
        var h = (get_doc_height() / 2) - 164;
        if(h > 0)
        {
            d.write('<style type="text/css">');
            d.write('#auth{margin-top:'+h+'px}\r\n');
            d.write('</style>');
        }</script>
        <div id="auth">
            <object classid="clsid:D27CDB6E-AE6D-11cf-96B8-444553540000" id="flashpass" width="294" height="328" codebase="http://fpdownload.macromedia.com/get/flashplayer/current/swflash.cab">
            <param name="movie" value="./swf/flashpass.swf">
            <param name="quality" value="high">
            <param name="bgcolor" value="#ececec">
            <param name="allowScriptAccess" value="sameDomain">
            <param name="flashvars" value="plid=123456">
            <embed src="./swf/flashpass.swf" quality="high" bgcolor="#ececec" flashvars="plid=123456" width="294" height="328" name="flashpass" align="middle" play="true" loop="false" quality="high" allowScriptAccess="sameDomain" type="application/x-shockwave-flash" pluginspage="http://www.adobe.com/go/getflashplayer"></embed>
            </object>
        </div>
    </body>
    </html>
```

Отправив запрос на ввод этого пароля, мне по этом же адресу game.php возвращается :

```
<head>
<SCRIPT src="./js/game.js"></SCRIPT>
<SCRIPT>
    view_frames();
</SCRIPT>
</head>
```

Где `<SCRIPT src="http://neverlands.ru/js/game.js"></SCRIPT>` сам скрипт который описывает фреймы и ссылки на них, а `<SCRIPT>view_frames();</SCRIPT>` запрашивает загрузку данных фреймов.

Я пытался создать локальный файл game.html и внести в него этот код, только с полными ссылками на скрипты и страницы, все вроде бы отлично прогрузилось, но верхний фрейм который http://neverlands.ru/main.php работает отлично, а вот нижний фрейм который отвечает за чат, не работает. Не получает сообщения и не отправляет их. В чем может быть проблема я уже просто даже не знаю.
Может у кого есть идем как можно это реализовать?

Comment: Safari mobile на iOS не поддерживает флэш. Рекомендую эту [библиотеку][1] для работы с Network.
[1]:https://github.com/AFNetworking/AFNetworking

Comment: Так приложение и не для ios, я, наверное, не указал, но думал, что из тегов будет понятно. И я сделал свой браузер на основе webkit.

Comment: Спасибо, разобрался я с AFNetworking, полностью переделал запрос. Но я так и не понял, как мне сделать, если оба пароля верны, чтобы закрылась моя loginWindowController и открылся сайт в mainWindowController.
Сейчас отредактирую мой первый пост, что получилось и как я пробовал открыть, помогите разобраться, если несложно.

Comment: Используйте NSNotificationCenter, чтобы уведомить ответственного за показ нужного контроллера о том, что логин успешно состоялся.

Comment: Я добавил код выше и описал саму проблему.

Comment: Думается мне, что проблема состоит в том, что нигде не хранится SessionID, так как, скорее всего, доступ к кукам из приложения нет. Я бы предложил сделать авторизацию по OAuth2 протоколу, либо с тем же успехом передавать SessionID с каждым запросом самостоятельно в headers. В общем, копать нужно куда-то в этом направлении. Проанализируйте реквесты.

Comment: А вот сейчас, к сожалению, вообще нечего не понял. :( 

Попытался загуглить передача SessionID, нашел вот такой код:

    NSArray *cookies = [[NSHTTPCookieStorage sharedHTTPCookieStorage] cookiesForURL: networkServerAddress];
    for (NSHTTPCookie *cookie in cookies) 
    {
        [[NSHTTPCookieStorage sharedHTTPCookieStorage] deleteCookie:cookie];
    }

Сейчас разбираюсь, оно ли это.

Answer (score 1):

Рекомендую использовать Adobe Air.

Comment: В каком плане?